# Error inserting pdf_tex from inscape with lualatex, "Missing \endcsname inserted"

Tags: luatex, inkscape

I am using this preamble as a template PomonaLgcsFormatting.tex:

```
%%% This file is the preamble for the Pomona Linguistics LaTeX Paper Template, which is also used for the Quick Reference Guide. If you are brand new to writing with LaTeX, we suggest NOT messing with it, and just writing your paper using the Paper Template. If you are getting more comfortable in LaTeX and want to add packages and commands, this is where you do it (when using this template).

%For stacking text, used here in autosegmental diagrams
\usepackage{stackengine}

%To combine rows in tables
\usepackage{multirow}

%geometry helps manage margins, among other things.
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

%Gives some extra formatting options, e.g. underlining/strikeout
\usepackage{ulem}

%For putting links into papers, also helps make cross-references in the paper smart references
\usepackage[colorlinks = true,
            linkcolor = blue,
            urlcolor  = blue,
            citecolor = blue,
            anchorcolor = blue]{hyperref} %smarter cross-references, these options turn links blue

%Use package/command below to create a double-spaced document, if you want one. Uncomment BOTH the package and the command (\doublespacing) to create a doublespaced document, or leave them as is to have a single-spaced document.
%\usepackage{setspace}
%\doublespacing 

%paragraph formatting
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\setlength{\parskip}{5pt} %plus 1 minus 1}
\setlength{\parindent}{30pt}
\usepackage{titlesec}

%use for special OT tableaux symbols like bomb and sad face. must be loaded early on because it doesn't play well with some other packages
\usepackage{fourier-orns}

%Basic math symbols 
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{amssymb}

%%%Gives shortcuts for glossing. The use of this package is NOT explained in the Quick Reference Guide, but the documentation is on CTAN for those that are interested. MJKD finds it handy for glossing. (https://ctan.org/pkg/leipzig?lang=en)
\usepackage{leipzig}

%Tables
\usepackage{caption} %For table captions
\usepackage{booktabs} %helps format tables

%For citations and bibliography - as of 9.1.2019 we don't explain citations in this Quick Reference Guide, but Pedro Martin's tutorial does (see links in the Guide).
\usepackage{natbib}

%For OT-style tableaux
\usepackage{ot-tableau}

%Fonts
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec} %This allows you to enter (via an IPA kayboard) IPA fonts and other symbols directly into LaTeX. Requires a particular setyp, see below.
\usepackage{libertine} %A font that actually contains many IPA symbols. This is the font you see in the preview to the right.

%to use these fonts, be sure that your typesetting engine is set to "XeLaTeX." In Overleaf, go to the Menu link on the top left (by the Overleaf icon), and under Settings be sure that the Compiler is set to "XeLaTeX." If you accessed this document via the Overleaf Pomona Linguistics template, all of this was already done for you.

%The Pomona Linguistics Paper Template in Overleaf is already set up for this, but you may run into this problem if you start building your own documents.

%highlights text with \hl{text}
\usepackage{color, soul}

%Drawing Syntax Trees
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}

%This specifies some formatting for the forest trees to make them nicer to look at
\forestset{
  nice nodes/.style={
    for tree={
      inner sep=0pt,
      fit=band,
    },
  },
  default preamble=nice nodes,
}

%% For numbered and glossed examples %%
\usepackage{gb4e}



%Changes the \maketitle command to be smaller and take up less space on a page. 
\makeatletter         
\def\@maketitle{   % custom maketitle 
\noindent {\Large \bfseries \color{black} \@title}  \\ \hrule \noindent \@author \\ \@date  
}

%The code below will draw a circle around a piece of text. This is very useful for drawing attention to a word in a data example. use the command \circled{text} where the argument (`text' here) is what you want to be circled. This is illustrated in the Quick Reference Guide and the Paper Template.

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\circled}[1]{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(word.base)]
\node[draw, rounded corners, text height=8pt, text depth=2pt, inner sep=2pt, outer sep=0pt, use as bounding box] (word) {#1};
\end{tikzpicture}
}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Useful Ling Shortcuts

\RequirePackage{leipzig}
%\RequirePackage{mathtools} % for \mathrlap

% % % Shortcuts  (borrowed from JZ, I'm still unsure exactly what xspace requires)
\RequirePackage{xspace}
\xspaceaddexceptions{]\}}

%This makes the \emptyset command be a nicer one
\let\oldemptyset\emptyset
\let\emptyset\varnothing
\newcommand{\nothing}{$\emptyset$}

%Not all of these are explained in the Quick Reference Guide, but they are here bc they are relevant to some of our students.
\newcommand{\1}{\rlap{$'$}\xspace}
\newcommand{\0}{\rlap{\textsuperscript{$ˆ{\circ}$}}\xspace}
\newcommand{\Lb}[1]{$\text{[}_{\text{#1}}$ } %A more convenient left bracket
\newcommand{\Rb}[1]{$\text{]}_{\text{#1}}$ } %A more convenient left bracket
\newcommand{\gap}{\underline{\hspace{1.2em}}}
\newcommand{\vP}{\emph{v}P}
\newcommand{\lilv}{\emph{v}}
\newcommand{\Abar}{A$'$-} %A more convenient A-bar notation
\newcommand{\ph}{$\varphi$\xspace} %A more convenient phi
\newcommand{\pro}{\emph{pro}\xspace}
\newcommand{\subs}[1]{\textsubscript{#1}} %A more convenient subscript
%\newcommand{\hd}{$^{\circ}$\xspace} %Symbol for printing head / degree symbol
\newcommand{\spells}{$\Longleftrightarrow$} %spellout arrow for morph spellout rules
\newcommand{\tr}[1]{\textit{t}\textsubscript{\textit{#1}}} %easy traces with subscript
\newcommand{\supers}[1]{\textsuperscript{#1}}

% Abbreviations for glossing, based on Leipzig
\newleipzig{hab}{hab}{habitual}
\newleipzig{rem}{rem}{remote}
\newleipzig{sm}{sm}{subject marker}
\newleipzig{t}{t}{tense}
\newleipzig{aa}{aa}{anti-agreement}
\newleipzig{pron}{pron}{pronoun}
\newleipzig{rec}{rec}{recent}
\newleipzig{om}{om}{object marker}
%\newleipzig{ipfv}{ipfv}{imperfective}
\newleipzig{asp}{asp}{aspect}
\newleipzig{lk}{lk}{linker}
\newleipzig{pcl}{pcl}{particle}
\newleipzig{stat}{stat}{stative}
\newleipzig{ints}{ints}{intensive}
\newleipzig{ascl}{ascl}{assertive subject clitic}
\newleipzig{nascl}{nascl}{non-assertive subject clitic}
\newleipzig{ta}{ta}{tense and/or aspect}
\newleipzig{assoc}{assoc}{associative marker}
\newleipzig{hon}{hon}{honorific}
%\newleipzig{whprt}{wh}{\wh particle}
\newleipzig{sa}{sa}{subject agreement}
\newleipzig{conj}{conj}{conjunction}
%\newleipzig{loc}{loc}{locative}
\newleipzig{expl}{expl}{expletive}
\newleipzig{rcm}{rcm}{reciprocal marker}
\newleipzig{pers}{pers}{persistive}
%\newleipzig{}{}{} %this is just to copy for when I want to add more

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%A couple of packages that seemed to prefer being called toward the end of the preamble

%This package provides macros for typesetting SPE-style phonological rules.
\usepackage{phonrule}

%For using Greek letters outside of math mode.
\usepackage{textgreek}


%Random, lets us use the XeLaTeX logo. Not important to the template at all.
\usepackage{metalogo}


%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% This is the end of the PREAMBLE
%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Here is my main file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\input{PomonaLgcsFormatting}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{\today} 

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}

Abstract

\end{abstract}

\section{Section}

Text

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \def\svgwidth{\columnwidth}
    { \input{figures/test.pdf_tex} }
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

And the "test.pdf_tex" is generated by Inkscape (version Inkscape 0.92.5 (2060ec1f9f, 2020-04-08):

```
%% Creator: Inkscape inkscape 0.92.5, www.inkscape.org
%% PDF/EPS/PS + LaTeX output extension by Johan Engelen, 2010
%% Accompanies image file 'algebraic-vof-problems.pdf' (pdf, eps, ps)
%%
%% To include the image in your LaTeX document, write
%%   \input{<filename>.pdf_tex}
%%  instead of
%%   \includegraphics{<filename>.pdf}
%% To scale the image, write
%%   \def\svgwidth{<desired width>}
%%   \input{<filename>.pdf_tex}
%%  instead of
%%   \includegraphics[width=<desired width>]{<filename>.pdf}
%%
%% Images with a different path to the parent latex file can
%% be accessed with the `import' package (which may need to be
%% installed) using
%%   \usepackage{import}
%% in the preamble, and then including the image with
%%   \import{<path to file>}{<filename>.pdf_tex}
%% Alternatively, one can specify
%%   \graphicspath{{<path to file>/}}
%% 
%% For more information, please see info/svg-inkscape on CTAN:
%%   http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/svg-inkscape
%%
\begingroup%
  \makeatletter%
  \providecommand\color[2][]{%
    \errmessage{(Inkscape) Color is used for the text in Inkscape, but the package 'color.sty' is not loaded}%
    \renewcommand\color[2][]{}%
  }%
  \providecommand\transparent[1]{%
    \errmessage{(Inkscape) Transparency is used (non-zero) for the text in Inkscape, but the package 'transparent.sty' is not loaded}%
    \renewcommand\transparent[1]{}%
  }%
  \providecommand\rotatebox[2]{#2}%
  \newcommand*\fsize{\dimexpr\f@size pt\relax}%
  \newcommand*\lineheight[1]{\fontsize{\fsize}{#1\fsize}\selectfont}%
  \ifx\svgwidth\undefined%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{249.20077515bp}%
    \ifx\svgscale\undefined%
      \relax%
    \else%
      \setlength{\unitlength}{\unitlength * \real{\svgscale}}%
    \fi%
  \else%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{\svgwidth}%
  \fi%
  \global\let\svgwidth\undefined%
  \global\let\svgscale\undefined%
  \makeatother%
  \begin{picture}(1,1)%
    \lineheight{1}%
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}%
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength,page=1]{test.pdf}}%
    \put(0.13680795,0.93333427){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lt]{\lineheight{1.25}\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{l}$\alpha = 1$\end{tabular}}}}%
    \put(0.60803537,0.93485421){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lt]{\lineheight{1.25}\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{l}$\alpha = 0$\end{tabular}}}}%
  \end{picture}%
\endgroup%
```

generates this error when I compile the "main.tex" with "lualatex main.tex":

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
let 
l.26 ...nput{figures/test.pdf_tex}
                                                   }
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`gb4e`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/gb4e) package is the culprit, I suppose one could say; as stated in its [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/gb4e/gb4e-doc.pdf) on the first page:

> The file `gb4e.sty` allows `_` (subscript) and `^` (superscript)` to be used in ordinary text, [...]

This interferes with the `\input{figures/test.pdf_tex}` call in your main file.

The documentation, on page 8, offers a solution which will resolve your problem:

> Sub- & superscripts (`_` and `^`) work outside mathmode, too.
>
> **Note:** This feature is known to cause problems for a number of other packages.  It  is  retained  for  backward  compatibility.  In  case  of  problems, you can disable it by adding the command `\noautomath` in your preamble  immediately  after  loading  the  gb4e  package.  You  can  also re-enable it later with the command `\automath`. [Added 2009/12/28]

So if you load the package in your preamble like so, it should work fine:

```
\usepackage{gb4e}
\noautomath
```

**PS:** Using the `no-math` option for package `fontspec` throws an option clash error for me, so I had to remove that option (alongside the reference to the external `test.pdf` file in your `test.pdf_tex` file) to successfully compile your document.