# Compile Error: TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [parameter stack size=10000]. When I cite with a wikipedia url on Latex on Overleaf

Tags: bibtex, errors, hyperref, citing

I am working with macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 version and I am doing a project report on Latex on overleaf.com. I have the errors on Latex: "LaTeX Error: Option clash for package hyperref." and "TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [parameter stack size=10000]" popping up when I cite a wikipedia page, and the error doesn't occur when I cite other webpages. And with this error, I cannot compile the pdf document with Latex. I need to submit mu project report in 4 days, can someone help me with it please.

**Here are the codes in my project:**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[lmargin=2.5cm,rmargin=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,textheight=23cm,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[L]{---}

\input{PomonaLgcsFormatting}

\title{ ---}
\author{---\
---}
\date{Spring 2020}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
Contents... \cite{wiki_GWAS}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{References}

\end{document}
```

The error disappears when I comment out the '\cite{wiki_GWAS}' part and occurs when I use this code.

**The following is the wikipedia reference I put in the .bib file:**

```
@misc{wiki_GWAS,
author = {Wikipedia contributors},
title = "Genome-wide association study--- {Wikipedia}{,} The Free Encyclopedia",
url = {https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genome-wide_association_study}
}
```

**Here are the screenshots of the errors if this helps.**[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome! After commenting out `\input{PomonaLgcsFormatting}` the code ran through on my machine, and according to the error message there is an option clash `PomonaLgcsFormatting`, a file the contents of which are not disclosed.

Comment: Off-topic: While loading the `geometry`, you can probably replace `lmargin=2.5cm,rmargin=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,textheight=23cm,margin=1in` with just `margin=1in` or, put differently, omit the first 4 options since their effects will get clobbered by `margin=1in`.

Comment: I just googled the file `PomonaLgcsFormatting`, which we don't have and found, https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/7724. Please always disclose double posts.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/542216/35864 has a file that purports to be some sort of `PomonaLgcsFormatting`. That file loads a lot of package, some twice (`leipzig`). That file loads `hyperref`, so you shouldn't load it in your preamble (the file loads `hyperref` comparably early, the usual advice is to load it as late as possible). It also loads `natbib`, so I suggest you don't load `\usepackage{cite}`.

Comment: Another comment that's not specifically aimed at the immediate problem at hand: The `plain` bibliography style is very old indeed and, as such, ignores `url` fields. If you need to show the entry's URL information, I suggest you (a) replace `\bibliographystyle{plain}` with `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}` and (b) replace `\usepackage{cite}` with `\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}`. For good measure, you should also make a third change: Load the `url` package (or, better still, the `xurl` package) before rather than after the `hyperref` package.

Comment: I think the bottom line is: If you don't have to use `PomonaLgcsFormatting`, remove the `\input{PomonaLgcsFormatting}` and add only those packages that you really need.